# How to put labels inside a cluster?

Tags: r, label, cluster-analysis

I'm making a cluster analysis and I have problems with the labels when a I have the plot finished. I've been checking in internet the solutions but I couldn't do anything.

I tried to keep the labels using:

```
rownames(df) <- df$labels
```

But when I change the scale the rownames are delete...

I have another column with the ID. But it would be better with labels.

Could have any way to join the result with my ID and Labels. The problem is **fviz_cluster** works with the rownames?

I have almost 100 n.

I'm amateur with this. Sorry for that. Thanks a lot

```
structure(list(label = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3", 
"C1", "C2", "C3"), ID = c(9, 44, 55, 57, 64, 59, 61, 20, 29), 
    A = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1), B = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 
    6, 4, 4), C = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2)), row.names = c("A1", 
"A2", "A3", "B1", "B2", "B3", "C1", "C2", "C3"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

demo <- as.data.frame(df)
rownames(demo) <- demo$label

head (demo) *#Ok, I have the labels in rownames!*

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  label    ID     A     B     C
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A1        9     1     1     0
2 A2       44     1     1     0
3 A3       55     1     1     1
4 B1       57     1     1     1
5 B2       64     2     1     3
6 B3       59     2     6     1
```

I need to scale the data... In this step I lost the rownames and the next step I can't use
the "demo" data because I need a table without labels...

```
demo1 <- scale(demo[c('A','B', 'C')]) 

              A          B          C
[1,] -0.6666667 -0.7995005 -1.1925696
[2,] -0.6666667 -0.7995005 -1.1925696
[3,] -0.6666667 -0.7995005 -0.2981424
[4,] -0.6666667 -0.7995005 -0.2981424
[5,]  1.3333333 -0.7995005  1.4907120
[6,]  1.3333333  1.4490946 -0.2981424


fviz_nbclust(demo1, pam, method = "wss")
pam <- pam(demo1, 2)
print(pam)

fviz_cluster(pam, data = demo1, ellipse.type = "norm", )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just assign the rownames after scaling:

```
library(cluster)
library(factoextra)

demo1 <- scale(df[c('A','B', 'C')]) 
rownames(demo1) = df$label

pam <- pam(demo1, 2)
fviz_cluster(pam, data = demo1, ellipse.type = "norm", )
```

[image]

Comment: Can one of you puleeze put in the necessary library calls?

Comment: yeah.. sorry forgot about it